# Combinatorics in Erlang

Tags: haskell, erlang

I want to find combinatorics of integer in Erlang, equivalent of this Haskell code:

```
composition 0 = [[]]
composition n = [x:rest | x <- [1..n], rest <- composition (n-x)]
```

so far I tried this which It doesn't work:

```
-module(combinatorics).
-export([comb/1]).
comb([]) -> []; 
comb(N) ->
        [[X|R] || X <- lists:seq(1,N),R=comb(N-X)].
```

The code return This error:

```
43> combinatorics:comb(2).
     ** exception error: no case clause matching []
             in function  combinatorics:'-comb/1-lc$^0/1-0-'/2 (combinatorics.erl, line 5)
             in call from combinatorics:'-comb/1-lc$^0/1-0-'/2 (combinatorics.erl, line 5)
```

Comment: What doesn't work? does it throw an error or give the wrong result for some input or something else?

Comment: Also your first clause is different, it should be `comb(0) -> [[]]` to match the Haskell code.

Comment: @Dogbert I update the question with Error

Comment: @Dogbert get same error for [[]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple errors in the translation:

1. The first clause should be `comb(0) -> [[]];`
2. You've done `R = comb(...)` instead of `R <- comb(...)` in the list comprehension.

With these changes, the code works:

```
-module(combinatorics).
-export([comb/1]).
comb(0) -> [[]];
comb(N) ->
    [[X|R] || X <- lists:seq(1,N), R <- comb(N-X)].
```

```
1> c(combinatorics).
{ok,combinatorics}
2> combinatorics:comb(1).
[[1]]
3> combinatorics:comb(2).
[[1,1],[2]]
4> combinatorics:comb(3).
[[1,1,1],[1,2],[2,1],[3]]
5> combinatorics:comb(4).
[[1,1,1,1],[1,1,2],[1,2,1],[1,3],[2,1,1],[2,2],[3,1],[4]]
```